# Does this circuit have any problems?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, signal, potentiometer, review

I built this circuit for removing DC from a signal, amplifying AC, and offset it via an op-amp for sending to an ADC.

AC signal amplitude is about 0 ~ 20 mV or 0 ~ 1 V.

The reason the signal ranges are different: they are measurements from different sources.

So I used a potentiometer for variable gain. In the real circuit I will use an MCP41100T-ISN digital variable register.

I simulated the circuit at [falstad.com](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEBmB0BskBMAWdn0B2SQwgTggUhCR2RoFMBaMMAKAENxD1wysQWBLzD8QADnBIWSMPHhRY8BGUhhhuBMlE8yvanPlsATiD3gsksDwuSDR0%20esibzqOCMB3biMs--kGwASma%20VmHuEDjUMKzuMdAIbNYCTq4u%20iCEILyZCUgAIgDCbADm-liQVjaWdlAm-mB%20QhH28GzeLbaCwnwCgVzIyLyVkjhgI1USUiAyHvLUTDDyKmo46zi4yJD8cW3tpl2iAkMiYvuBpqfg6yDjIrcXHSjDNzgvZ-3P9293E4JTQLla5YXAfFCQd4xNgAYzu4mooxotyR1GQ0CwZCx2JxOPQzGyOGgyD04jIpGwTQQ4hwZEUcHY1nemCsfkIlXAmHA8wUy0gSCCDAAzgBLIUAFw4ADsYQxvv8kTgEQC7GwAEazZACJV3Qjva6BbwIW5NSTG96ozg5dmCMGEBACUHvKzSdQ8hRgaC0rHiBFYUSoJXZT2yBYNc3dFndfYNQivU0SODRnnPIgCCbUNMq%20ree2OsEIxFgw2Jgx%20Qu2qGpm0Z60CdBV7wVhMVhv1OFZtutqHgRLMOSKbb%208TqYgN9DDSz6JTsEIIGq9B2SLoxO6IxLxRRJUzzkaLmzbHugg40A%20Q0%208VD9F7tcq7lAOi8odB1Ev3w91iGNz8frO4aGmBWToSMqwEXIEyDvAAXgwUoMMYTDovQBjQIQYB0EuxwjvAWAEu4JzEvUUEgWiHK%20kWFogDBcEIUhZQkSgZHKga9QAA5mCiYJkLcWoGPEzzkZWHEWsWAnMRy3H6hygQAB49PQvp3HgZhRII7wACoABZigAOkKHDGAwHB6bpQqiqUUocAANmwAD2KCSG21DRGQZqKBABhsMgYwgAAYh5kSzBAACCRR6QAshwMl6QAarZVmSqUcreXcfkQMhUiLBAvmGQAjgArrBMIAJ5sEAA); it showed no problems.

Now I am going to test this circuit on a breadboard.

Before the test I ask you if there are no errors or worry points.

I suggest these points to make it easier to give an opinion:

1. current via potentiometer
2. gain range

If you find it hard to give an opinion, please tell me "this design maybe has no problems" or "maybe some problem exists".
That would also be helpful.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry about the language issues, but you do need to spend some time on your design thoughts. When you write "filtering" that can mean most anything. We can see the schematic and, if willing to spend time, perhaps able to suss out a few details. But it is much better if you just tell us, directly. In short, write down as much of your design thinking as possible.

Comment: @jonk filtering which i mentioned is remove DC at raw signal.
This design remove DC from signal and amplifying AC and offset it.
I want know is this design have some problem like over current, over voltage.
The simplist question is "many people use opamp like this?"

Comment: What is your input signal voltage range and your required output signal voltage range and what power supply voltages do you have available

Comment: @James that is included in simulation what I wrote in post. DC level : 0~6V AC level : 0~1V.
I will use power input 24V and 24V to +12V and -12V double pole converter MD224D-12EI.

Comment: So, is it true to say that you have a 0 to 1 V input signal or a 0 to 20 mV input signal riding on a dc level which can be anywhere between 0 and 6 V? Also what is the required output signal range for the ADC input? Presumably the ADC is powered from a voltage other than +12 V, what voltage supply is it?

Comment: @james according my simulation, signal processing to 0V to 3.3V in range.
+12V and -12V supply for opamp. 0~6V with 0 ~1V ripple is signal. And opamp circuit filtering DC value and amplifying AC value.

Comment: When the DC level of your input signal is +6 V, the first op amp will try to drive its output to - 12 V. That's no good with a - 12 V supply. I'd suggest removing the first two stages and putting your input signal straight into the capacitor as long as the inversion is not a problem for you. Also 330 nF and 1 k gives a cut-off frequency of 482 Hz. So if you are dealing with signals frequencies lower than that you'll need to increase the value of the cap. 100 k output is too high a source resistance for driving an ADC.

Comment: ... Also a capacitor (say 47uF) is needed across the 33 k resistor to filter any noise on the 2.5 V supply.